# Android -simple deployment to emulator (through command line)

Tags: android, deployment

I want to do the deployment to emulator through command line

based on this tutorial
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html

I should run

```
ant debug
adb install -r bin/MyApp.apk
```

The run is successfully.

```
KitApp  adb install -r bin/KitApp.apk
912 KB/s (279569 bytes in 0.299s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/KitApp.apk
Success
```

However, the emulator does not update my new app.
But when I use GUI , eclipse, to click run, the apps does update it automatically in emlator

What steps is going wrong?
I am a newbie on android-development.

Comment: update means it relaunches your app with the changes you made?

Comment: check the answer posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to launch the activity

```
adb shell am start -n <packagename>/<classname with packagename>
```

or

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n <packagename>/<classname with packagename>
```

Eg:

```
adb shell am start -n com.example.myactivity/com.example.myactivity.MainActivity
```

Where you have your **MainActivity** defined with the following Intent-Filter

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```